# How to create a file comprising of xml data by rest web service in Spring?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rest, spring-mvc

Hello guys I am new to spring and rest, I wanted to create a small module in which a user submits some values lets say first-name, last name etc from UI and the request goes to a REST service which generates a file or .xml file having that data serialized into xml format. Its kind of xml bean serialization. Can anybody tell how this can be achieved. A sample code would be a great help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tutorial here: [Build RESTful web services with the Spring](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html).

From tutorial:

In `rest-servlet.xml` it tells to use Jaxb2Mashaller for object XML mapping:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller"
class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
        <value>dw.spring3.rest.bean.Employee</value>
        <value>dw.spring3.rest.bean.EmployeeList</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

And in `getEmployee` it demonstrate how to receive `REQUEST` parameters and pass them to `getEmployee` method and then employee object as serialized XML response. You can easily modify this `getEmployee` method to save serialized employee object to .xml file instead of sending it as response.

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/employee/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getEmployee(@PathVariable String id) {
        Employee e = employeeDS.get(Long.parseLong(id));
        return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "object", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and will let you know :)